# Support Vector regression in tuned mood using K-fold method in R

Tags: r, regression, svm

I had been looking for the way of performing SVR with the K-Fold method in R and finally, I have found how to perform this and when I use only SVM() function in R the script works perfectly  but when I try to tune the SVM I get error and I think, because I have to change my for loop in some sense which I do not know.

The error says "(subscript) logical subscript too long"

the code is as follows:

```
library(plyr)
library(e1071)


# cross-validation  
# predict the AWC 


data<-read.csv("data.csv",header = T)

k = 5 
# sample from 1 to k, nrow times (the number of observations in the data)
data$id <- sample(1:k, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
list <- 1:k


prediction <- data.frame()
testsetCopy <- data.frame()


for (i in 1:k){
# remove rows with id i from dataframe to create training set
# select rows with id i to create test set
train.set <- subset(data, id %in% list[-i])
testset <- subset(data, id %in% c(i))

# Tuning SVM
mymodel <- tune(method = svm,train.y = train.set$AWC,train.x = 
train.set, kernel="radial")

#get the best model out of tuned process.
mymodel1<-mymodel$best.model
# remove the response column 1, AWC
temp <- as.data.frame(predict(mymodel1, testset[,-1]))
# append this iteration's predictions to the end of the prediction data frame
prediction <- rbind(prediction, temp)

# append this iteration's test set to the test set copy data frame
# keep only the AWC Column
testsetCopy <- rbind(testsetCopy, as.data.frame(testset[,1]))

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `tune` does the work for you and you don't need to write loops. Look at the R documentation for `tune`. There is an example there.

Also, by setting `k=5`, it looks like you have 5 data points and leave one out at a time. Perhaps this would work better `sample(1:nrow(data), round(0.80*nrow(data)),replace = TRUE)` although there is no need for this as `tune` does all that.

Comment: Yes, you alright. I was confused. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: I have a question now, since the tuning method is doing an inner 10 fold cross-validation and splitting the data to train and test set, How can I retrieve the result individually from each fold not only for the best model?